# How do edit the last occurrence of a particular string in powershell

Tags: powershell

My text file contains G-Code with the code "G94" appearing 5 times at different line numbers.

`G94`
`G94`
`G94`
`G94`
`G94`

I need to change the last occurrence of "G94" to

```
G94 
/M16
```

but I keep getting no edit at all.

I'm trying this:

```
$text = get-content C:\cncm\g94.txt
$i = 1
$replace = 5 #Replace the 5th match

ForEach ( $match in ($text | select-String "G94" -AllMatches).matches) 
{
    $index = $match.Index
    if ( $i -eq $replace )
    {
        $text.Remove($index,"G94".length).Insert($index,"G94 n /M16")
    }
    $i++
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regexp with negative lookahead on a string that contains the entire file.

- Replacing last occurrence in the entire file - `(?s)` DOTALL mode allows `.*` to span across new line characters:

  ```
  $text = [IO.File]::ReadAllText('C:\cncm\g94.txt')
  $text = $text -replace '(?s)G94(?!.*?G94)', "G94`n/M16"
  ```
- Replacing last occurrence in every line - `(?m)` MULTILINE mode:

  ```
  $text = [IO.File]::ReadAllText('C:\cncm\g94.txt')
  $text = $text -replace '(?m)G94(?!.*?G94)', "G94`n/M16"
  ```

Comment: Doesn't do what I need. It adds the "/M16" but on the same line and after every G94. I only need it after the last.

Comment: Oh, I've just added the new line character, that's trivial. The code [works correctly](https://puu.sh/qhnvp/370121d62c.png) here on PS5, and AFAIK it should work even on PS2. Maybe you use PS1?

Comment: Ah, I believe you have the original text all on the same line. Each G94 is on a different line. In the original file there is a bunch of other data so one G94 may be on line 12 then the next on line 40 etc.

Comment: the `(?s)` worked! Thanks. Another question, how would you change it for an identical situation but for the first occurrence?

Comment: I would use the `[regex]` class method that accepts a number of replacements to be made: `$text = ([regex]'G94').Replace($text, "G94\`n/M16", 1)`

Answer (score 1):

`$text` is an array of strings, how are you calling `Remove()` without getting an exception? First because `Remove()` only takes one parameter, second because you can't remove from a fixed length array.

I'm thinking:

```
$text = get-content C:\cncm\g94.txt

$fifthMatch = ($text | select-string "G94" -AllMatches)[4]
$line = $text[$fifthMatch.LineNumber]

$line = $line.Remove($fifthMatch.index,"G94".length).Insert($fifthMatch.index,"G94 `n /M16")

$text[$fifthMatch.LineNumber] = $line
$text | out-file c:\cncm\g942.txt
```

Comment: I get two errors. 
'You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:6 char:1
+ $line = $line.Remove($fifthMatch.index,"G94".length).Insert($fifthMat ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull'  
and

Comment: Sorry, new to this site. first error is: you cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
Second is: Index was outside the bounds of the array.